# Clear Textfield data for the flutter appium textfiled

Tags: flutter, dart, appium, appium-android, appium-flutter

I am currently working on the e2e test for the flutter application where i am using Appium, I am on the scenario where i want to clear all the textfield data. But its not working as expected.

```
    await this.driver.elementClear("object name to clear");
```

I am using the elementClear Method to clear the field **elementClear** does not work. Any idea if any one has faced any kind of issue.

Following is what i am passing to the elementClear

```
descendant({of: byValueKey('capture_amount_field'),matching: byType('TextField'),firstMatchOnly: true });
```

Comment: Can you share what you are passing to elementClear ?

Comment: elementClear is expecting flutter object which i am accessing via the key. Editing it in the question please check

Comment: did you try this : driver.elementClear(find.byType('TextField')) as per https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver

Comment: yes i am suing the same